# 16.04: File with no hardlink

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, hard-link

I have a directory with these files on an Ubuntu 16.04 server:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup   162034 Apr  1  2019 accounts.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup  2336191 Apr 17  2019 app.access.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup   109801 Apr 17  2019 app.error.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup  5530832 Mar  2 16:00 blocs.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup     8728 Mar  2 16:14 access.log
-rwxrwxrwx 0 nobody nogroup     9337 Mar  2 15:15 access.log.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup     9067 Mar  2 15:18 access.log.2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 10485699 Mar  2 14:53 access.log.3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup    60801 Jan  6 09:21 access.log.4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup    57034 Jan  6 09:22 access.log.5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nobody nogroup 10485729 Jan  4 17:59 access.log.6
```

How can `access.log.1` have "0" hardlinks ?
How can I delete `access.log.1` ? (`rm access.log.1` gives me a `No such file or directory` error) ...

Comment: My guess is that the file was already deleted but is still accessed by a process - can you check with `fuser access.log.1`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the fuser command (I'm in a docker container btw)...

Comment: "No access" means no rights or not installed? `apt-get install psmisc`

Comment: Or use `lsof` to determine if the file is in use: `lsof | grep access.log.1`